# Making an axis give Natural Log instead of log10 when log = "y" in R plot

Tags: r, function, plot

### Background:

When we set `log = "y"` in an R `curve()` call, R converts the function to be plotted to output `log10` values of the function's original values (***i.e., without needing to change the the original function to output `log10` values***).

### Question:

I was wondering if it might be possible to have R plot the `log` (i.e., natural log) of the function to be plotted (***i.e., THIS TIME  without needing to change the original function to output `log` values***)?

### Example:

As an example, below, R is plotting the `log10` values of function `LF` only by setting `log = "y"` (***without needing to change the `LF` function to output `log10` values***). In the same manner, could we have R plot the `log` of the **LF function (without needing to change the `LF` function to output `log` values)?**

```
 LF = function(x) dnorm(250, x, 2)*dnorm(265, x, 2)*dnorm(259, x, 2)

 curve(LF, from = 250, to = 266, log = "y")
```

Comment: All log transformations are equivalent to within a constant multiple, so a chart with a log-e transformation will look the same as one with log-10.

Comment: @AndrewGustar, they will "***look***" the same but the values are different, are n't they?

Comment: If you are plotting `log(y)` on a linear scale then the values will be different, but if you are plotting `y` on a log scale, then the values of `y` on the axis will be the same whatever the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew Gustar is absolutely correct that the values will be the same, as will the shape.

The only difference will be the tick marks

The scales package gives some options

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
```

Dummy ggplot

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))
```

Natural Log Scale showing labels **in terms of e**

```
p + stat_function(fun = LF) + xlim(250,266) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans(), 
                         breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x)),
                         labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x)))
```

[image]

Alternative plotting log(LF)

```
logLF <- function(x) log(LF(x))
p + stat_function(fun = logLF) + xlim(250,266)
```

[image]